# How to Add attachments to an existing work item in Azure DevOps using c#

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, attachment

Would you please provide a code sample on how to add attachments (text file and an image) to an existing work item in Azure DevOps using C#.

Comment: Here's the REST API for attachment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0 and here's some C# samples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/rest/samples?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thank you Amittai. I am able to connect to Azure DevOps and upload the file using the following code but I am not sure how to attach it to a workitem using POST as the sample from the link you sent.                                                                                                        AttachmentReference attachment = workItemTrackingHttpClient.CreateAttachmentAsync(@"C:\TestDocument.txt").Result;

Comment: @Nick edit your question with the code you tried and what exactly you didn't success

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some [blog](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2018/12/14/azure-devops-services-rest-api-6-upload-and-download-work-item-attachments/) and cases: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795797/adding-attachment-using-api-for-visual-studio-team-services-was-visual-studio-o) . [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47998600/file-attachment-to-a-work-item-tfs-2015)  with C# code samples, you can refer to them.

```
using (FileStream attStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var att = WitClient.CreateAttachmentAsync(attStream, filePathSplit[filePathSplit.Length – 1]).Result; // upload the file
    
    JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();
    
    patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
        Operation = Operation.Add,
        Path = "/relations/-",
        Value = new
        {
            rel = "AttachedFile",
            url = att.Url,
            attributes = new { comment = “Comments for the file “ + filePathSplit[filePathSplit.Length – 1] }
        }
    });

    var workItem = UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, workItemId).Result;
}
```